# How to save android web driver screenshots while executing test cases?

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver, android-webview

I am getting failure exception while taking the device screenshots

my code as below:

```
//open the page
driver.get("http://wikipedia.com");
//take another screenshot
try {
        File screenshot = new File("screenshot1.png");
            File tmpScreenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);           
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Failed to take screenshot."+e.getMessage());
        }

        //quit
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Can any body help me out this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to execute your code but didn't get the exception, although i didn't get the screenshot either. I have modified your code a bit see if this work for you

```java
driver.get("http://wikipedia.com");

File screenshot = new File("screenshot1.png");
File tmpScreenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(tmpScreenshot, screenshot);
System.out.println("the screenshot printed at:- " + screenshot.getAbsolutePath());
```